# Learning Python/Apache/Linux

Tags: python, linux, apache

Im currently a C# developer with a few years of experiance building websites with IIS/.net.

I want to do a pet project using Python/Apache/Linux.

Can anyone recomend some resources to help me pick up open source programming? In particular my knowledge of Apache and linux server administration is very low. Setting up Apache and getting it to work with  Python seems daunting.

Comment: are you going to use Django after your initial setup?

Comment: Yes i im intending to use Django

Comment: cool, I added you a link there. Although, if you really wanna go deep with Django, I Will recommend to follow the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/  as it describes the complete setup process on linux - distro independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also some useful links from me :

1) [Building LAMP](http://www.lamphowto.com/) (skip the PHP part)

2) [Setup Python](http://www.blog.highub.com/python/python-core/install-python-on-linux-ubuntu/) on Linux

3) [Embedding Apache2 and Python](http://www.howtoforge.com/embedding-python-in-apache2-with-mod_python-debian-etch)

4) [Installing Django](http://jeffbaier.com/articles/installing-django-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server/) on Ubuntu

5) **Recommended**: Official Django [Complete Setup Guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/install/)

Answer (score 0):

A good resource for python learning are Google Lectures ([link](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/)), also about Apache you should look at the official apache [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/install.html) (there is no easy way). You should look for [CGI](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/CGI/cgi1.html), because it's a good place to start web application programming.

Update:
As suggested below, for more serious web programming you should look for WSGI, which it's a more modern standard. While, it's pretty easy to learn WSGI if one understands CGI.

Comment: CGI? No, really, it doesn't. Look for WSGI.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I mean is a good place to start. Various adapters(wrappers) are learned later , when one is more comfortable with tools.

Comment: @6D65 While CGI is good for writing simple hacks, it is no way to do web application development.

Comment: @plaes Yes, you're right. It's even more true because he wants to use Django.

Answer (score 0):

The official Django Tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ is perhaps one of the best resource for you to get up and going.

To run a production web application, it is not necessary to know the intricacies of Apache/nginx etc. There are plenty of cloud hosting providers that just take your code on commit and have it deployed automatically. You may want to refer [djangozoom.com](http://djangozoom.com/), [ep.io](https://www.ep.io/) or many similar hosting providers.